# Fill handle doesn't work, Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I write *one* into one cell (B1) and *two* into the cell below of it (B2) like the shape 1, and select both from up to down and then pull the fill handle of the lower right corner until B7, I expect these cells are filled from *one* through *seven*. But it just copies those *one* and *two*.

[image]

When I pull the fill handle by right clicking, the *Fill Series* is grayed out in right click options!
As well as, the *Series* dialog box (*Home > Editting group > Fill drop-down list > Series*) seems normal.

[image]

What is the problem? Why fill handle doesn't work please?

Comment: Try if it works with months' names, those work fine in German while the german number's names don't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom list of values.  Go to the **Excel Options > Advanced** and scroll down to find the button **Edit Custom Lists**.

Enter the list values into the box for new lists, each value on a new row. You can also import lists from a text file. In the other box you can see that the month names are also custom lists that come as default Excel settings. No magic.

Once the custom list has been defined, it will be used by the fill handle. See the 'sieben' in the tool tip in the screenshot.

[image]